# count words in LIST without separators

Tags: ksh

I have the following simple ksh code:

```
 MY_LIST=first,second,third
 NUM_IN_LIST=` echo $MY_LIST | sed s"/,/ /g" | wc -w `
 print $NUM_IN_LIST
 3
 [[ $NUM_IN_LIST = 3 ]] && print match

 but I dont get the match print -:(
```

maybe because some spaces?

can I get some other suggestion to count and print the words  in $MY_LIST ? (after remove the "," seperator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works for me.

Here's an alternative:

```
MY_LIST=first,second,third
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
array=($MY_LIST)
IFS=$saveIFS
NUM_IN_LIST=${#array[@]}
print $NUM_IN_LIST
[[ $NUM_IN_LIST = 3 ]] && print match
```

Comment: another example is to use the awk '{print NF}' to count the elements in MY_LIST

Comment: You need `set -f` before the unquoted `$MY_LIST`, in case the string contains globbing characters. But using `IFS` is more complicated that it needs to be in ksh.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but only if `$MY_LIST` doesn't contain any of various special characters:

- `echo $MY_LIST` should be `printf %s "$MY_LIST"` or `print -r -- "$MY_LIST"`. The lack of quotes tells the shell to expant globbing characters `\\*?[`. It also tells the shell to split words at spaces, although that wouldn't matter here except for the next problem.
- Using `echo` additionally causes interpretation of backslashes and a leading `-` in some circumstances.
- `sed s"/,/ /g" makes both commas and spaces word separators.

An additional issue, explaining why your final test doesn't work, is that `wc -w` produces output with leading spaces, which are captured in `$NUM_IN_LIST`. `print $NUM_IN_LIST` performs word splitting on `$NUM_IN_LIST`, so it ends up just printing the digits; do `print "$NUM_IN_LIST"` to see the difference. The `[[ … ]]` construct inhibits word splitting, and `=` is a string comparison operator, so you are correctly told that `'       3'` is not the same thing as `'3'`. `[[ $NUM_IN_LIST -eq 3 ]]` or `[ $NUM_IN_LIST = 3 ]` would have been true (but neither is a real solution, they're just limited workarounds).

---

A pure ksh way to show the number of comma-separated fields is

```
commas=${MY_LIST//[!,]/}
NUM_IN_LIST=${#commas}
```

If anyone needs a POSIX sh solution, replace the first line by `commas=$(printf %s "$MY_LIST" | tr -dc ,)`.